# Hashing a dictionary from mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, dictionary, string-hashing

I have a problem with mysql database when I try to find a code that can help me with getting multiple results for the word "get". I find only one suggestion when I search through a database. Here is what I get

Enter a word to search_______________: get

Consider this alternative____________: access (E.g. You can access some of the best lawyers)

But I have other entries that are also important when it comes to the word "get", and the words that can fit here as alternatives are 7. So what can I do in Java to solve this problem? I have a table called grammarchecker, and a column named wrongwords, while the other one is rightwords.

How can I code this in Java? I have watched some videos on hashing a dictionary, regular expressions on matching and pattern matching on arrays, but regular expressions cannot do it in JAVA on a mysql database. Secondly, when it comes to Mysql database, hashing is mostly done on a text file. Is it possible to get multiple results for the word "get" with this kind of function in java: rs.next()

Because I don't know how Hashing a dictionary from mysql database is possible. I just want a solution.

My problem is getting multiple answers from Mysql database for different words through the scanner in java. Not just for the word get!

Comment: What in the world does hashing have to do with such a problem?  Do you perhaps mean "indexing"?

Comment: My problem is getting multiple answers from Mysql database for any word that is inputted through the scanner in java.

Comment: This sounds like a problem that would best be solved in the database, rather than in Java.  Either way, though, it's unclear how to recognize the results you want to retrieve.

Comment: I want to enter any word to check, and then offer different suggestions by retrieving them from the database in the second column

Comment: In order to obtain multiple results, you need to perform a query that will return multiple results (rows).  Are you performing such a query?

Comment: Not just the word get, because if it was for one word only I would do it from the database. But if it is multiple words, I need to find a way to do it.

Comment: I have been searching online but could not find something that could fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret your question to say that given a user-provided word, you want to look up that word among the `wrongwords` in your table `grammarchecker`, and obtain all of the associated `rightwords`.  That might look like this:

```
List<String> findAlternativeWords(String userWord, Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select rightwords from gammarchecker where wrongwords = ?");

    try {
        ResultSet results;

        ps.setString(1, userWord);
        results = ps.executeQuery();

        while (results.next()) {
            words.add(results.getString(1));
        }
    } finally {
        ps.close();
    }

    return words;
}
```

That assumes you already have an open database connection that you will pass to the method.  Note that I suggest a `PreparedStatement` here, as opposed to building an SQL statement directly in a string, because user-provided data must be handled very carefully.  Otherwise, you open yourself (in this case) to an SQL injection attack.  Inserting the user's word via a prepared statement parameter protects you from that.

Comment: Give me one minute to check if the code will work please.

Comment: OK. This section says: List<String> findAlternativeWords       ; expected, not a statement. What should I do because I have already replaced my connection code to the database with yours?

Comment: I did not provide database connection code.  I provided code that assumes you already have a connection, which you will provide as a method argument.  I moreover cannot advise you on details of how to incorporate the method I offered into your code, as that depends on your code.  If you're not prepared to do some of the work yourself then I suggest you make use of your editor's "undo" feature and forget you ever asked.

Comment: The code is not working. Do you have the whole code so I can indent it through?

Comment: Thank you. I will try to edit it as best as I can. I am only a beginner

Comment: Anybody please help! This guy did not help me at all.

Comment: Please please help. Anybody!